# Toyota Taco 06 2.7l 4c, Why are we having Ignition and idle problems after a head gasket repair?

Tags: toyota, ignition, rpm, head-gasket

We just replaced the head gasket and sealed with silicone and new gaskets. After our process was complete we discovered the engine idle would go from 1,000 rpms for 8 sec to 500 rpms 8 seconds sometimes even 350 rpms about. What did we mess up?? We already checked the status of the ignition coils they are good read 6.6 on the ohms of a voltage meter. If anyone has a check list of possible issues that would help so much. [video of my explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EM9gr4nLiB0)

Comment: All pipes connected properly, all sensors as well... Any codes showing?

Comment: electronic throttle? did you do a throttle relearn? is there any scan data you can show us?

Comment: To clarify: **where** did you put the silicone? Surely not on the head or gasket??

Comment: For a brief moment I actually thought the car was actually called Taco..

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing to check in case of hunting idle here is unmetered air or a vacuum leak.

A quick (not comprehensive) checklist:

- Are all intake-side hoses connected?

  Possible suspects: brake booster vacuum line, crankcase ventilation line, EGR line...
- Is the idle air control valve functioning as it should?
- Are there signs of an obvious leak?

  If it's bad enough, there should be an audible hissing sound around the engine